# datetime from stripe being formatted with angularjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, angularjs, stripe-payments

So stripe is giving me `1374030547` as a date string.

When I use `{{ myDateVar | date: 'mediumData'}}` in angular

It's returning JAN 16, 1970

Rails is able to take the same date string and return 2013-07-16 which is the accurate date.

So what am I doing wrong with angular here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date string needs to be in Millis, so if you have the value as 1374030547000, it should return today's date. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4fAS/) demonstrating this.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
 $scope.mytime = "1374030547000";   
}
```